# Issues with logging out from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a web app which lets user log in with Facebook.
**The flow is:**
1. Click on login with FB
2. Login to FB
3. Redirect back to the web app

For security reasons (the app is going to run on iPads in customers stores) I need to logout the user from Facebook immediately after I receive response from FB - the app no longer interact with FB API).

**After user logs into FB, an approval dialog appears which lets user**
1. grant access to the app
2. deny access to the app

Then, user is redirected to the app where response is processed.

```
public function facebook()
{
    try {
        $fbUser = Faceoff::me();
        $user = UserCreator::withProfile( $fbUser );
        Auth::login($user);

        $url = Faceoff::getLogoutUrl(['next' => 'url to protected area']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $url = Faceoff::getLogoutUrl(['next' => 'url to login page']);
    }

    Faceoff::destroySession();
    return Redirect::to($url);
}
```

If user grants access `try` block is executed, if user denies access `catch` block is executed instead and logout URL with appropriate `next` parameter is generated.
User is redirected to that logout URL right back.
So far so good.

The problem is: **I cannot logout user from FB if user does not grant access to the app.**
But I can, if access is granted.

Is there a solution for this, or this is intended behaviour?

PS-1: `Faceoff` is just a wrapper for Laravel.
PS-2: Sorry for such a story, I just need you to know what I try to achieve and where the problem starts.

**Thank you for any direction which could lead to the solution!**

Comment: Of course this is intended behavior, otherwise _every_ website I visit could log me out of FB, whether I want that to happen or not – and therefor it needs an active user access token.

Comment: And btw., it is not wise to have a large number of users log in on a very limited set of devices in a frequent fashion – that is very likely to trigger Facebook’s security algorithms, that will think something shady is going on … and can lead to your users having to answer additional security questions, get in other trouble concerning their own accounts, up to your app getting blocked.

Comment: Yeah, it i take a look from this point, it is right behaviour.
If you turn your comment into answer I can mark it! Thanks.
BTW, dropping iPad idea completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is: I cannot logout user from FB if user does not grant access to the app.
>    But I can, if access is granted.
>
> Is there a solution for this, or this is intended behaviour?

Of course this is intended behavior, otherwise *every* website I visit could log me out of FB, whether I want that to happen or not – and therefor it needs an active user access token.

---

And btw., it is not wise to have a large number of users log in on a very limited set of devices in a frequent fashion – that is very likely to trigger Facebook’s security algorithms, that will think something shady is going on … and can lead to your users having to answer additional security questions, get in other trouble concerning their own accounts, up to your app getting blocked.